# One session per tab

Tags: javascript, session, cookies, tabs

We have this (really simple) web-desktop-environment for intranet.

So what I want, is have the user's session limited to the current tab.
Instead of a cookie session-token, i would store this value in javascript, and

- send the token as get-var in the url
- make each request a post, and send the token as post-var

I'm looking here to what option i should use, and if anyone perhaps sees some alternatives.

Comment: Just make it a urlbased session?

Comment: As of now i work with a session cookie. I'm trying to decide which approach is the best to limit the session to one tab. I was planning to go for the first solution, as Chris mentioned. But then i remembered, this could leak the session id through the referrer field. Maybe it's safer to take the second option.

Comment: http is a sessionless protocol, and even though sessions exist, they are designed to live at the browser level, not the tab level.    Whenever I get myself in a situation like this I go back to the drawing board and think really hard about what I'm trying to accomplish and whether or not I truly need to work against the grain of my technology stack to accomplish it.  The answer is almost always "no".